# Constructing object based on true/false conditions

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I am usually constructing objects that do have fields in them or do not have them based on a condition so

```
let data
if(something === true) {
  data = {
    name: 'String',
    something: 'Something'
  }
else {
  data = {
    name: 'String'
  }
}
```

but this seems like a very "dirty way to do this" as data needs to be redefined every time + if there were more if conditions this would become quiet big chunk of code. Is there a more concise way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not assign the common values first, then just add the additional ones later.  `var data = {name: 'String'};  if(something){ data.something = 'Something'; }`?

Comment: Simplest way is to let data = {}; and then in your if, just do data.name='String'; data.something = 'Something' etc etc But there are tons of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: There is no such thing as a [JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/1048572). And what you have here isn't JSON anyway (lacking quotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just conditionally add properties to the object - you don't need to define the whole thing in one go as an object literal.

```
let data = {
    name: 'String'
};
if (something) {
    data.something = 'Something';
}
```

Comment: Of course, but there's something vaguely unsatisfying about this.

Comment: @torazaburo: The repetition of the identifier `data` maybe? I like your approach, but for some reason I probably still wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use can a ternary operator like this:

```
let data = {
  name: 'String',
  something: (something) ? "Something" : undefined,
}
```

practically this should work because `undefined` is what you get when trying to access a non-existing object property,
but keep in mind you're adding an enumerable property to the object.

Comment: You should not use that unless you know how it is different from the original result, though.

Comment: @Bergi the difference is that property exists but is undefined, or is there something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You should add a paragraph about that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` as follows, because it ignores non-object parameters:

```js
let data
let something = true
data = Object.assign(
    { name: 'String' },
    something && {something: 'Something'}
)

console.log(data)
```

Or, if you prefer

```
something ? {something: 'Something'} : {}
```